# INNER JOIN on multiple rows acts as if rows does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I need to extract stats of students registered per province. A student has an address with a postal code; the postal code is linked to a magisterial district; the magisterial district is linked to a province. To build a select using inner joins is fairly straight forword.

However, from the student adress to the postal code (code = 1911) I have a problem as there are multiple records for the postal code with different suburb names; see the data extract below.

```
1911    FLORA GARDENS,Vanderbijlpark    7702    VANDERBIJLPARK
1911    HENBYL                          7702    VANDERBIJLPARK
1911    LUMIER                          7702    VANDERBIJLPARK
1911    NORTHDENE,Vanderbijlpark        7702    VANDERBIJLPARK
1911    PARK SOUTH                      7702    VANDERBIJLPARK
1911    STAAL                           7702    VANDERBIJLPARK
1911    VANDERBIJLPARK                  7702    VANDERBIJLPARK
1911    ZUURFONTEIN                     7702    VANDERBIJLPARK
```

When I do an INNER JOIN select like this,

```
FROM gen.getadr
INNER JOIN stud.iadbio ON getunum = iadstno
INNER JOIN stud.ibvpos ON getpcode = ibvcode
INNER JOIN stud.ibdmag ON ibvcode = ibdcode
```

no rows are returned.

When I change this to a LEFT join

```
FROM gen.getadr
INNER JOIN stud.iadbio ON getunum = iadstno
LEFT JOIN stud.ibvpos ON getpcode = ibvcode
LEFT JOIN stud.ibdmag ON ibvcode = ibdcode
```

I get the rows *without* the data from ibvpos and idbmag. I can thus not join with the provinces table to count the students per province.

Is there a way that I can indicate that the join between getadr (student address) and ibvpos (definition of postal codes - multiple rows) must be based on a unique match between getpcode and ibvcode?

The complete select statement looks like this:

```
SELECT getunum, getnumtype, getaddrtype, GETCSn, getsdate, getedate, gettac,    
getsyscrt 
, getadr1, getadr2, getadr3, getadr4, getpcode, ibvtown, ibdname
FROM gen.getadr
 INNER JOIN stud.iadbio ON getunum = iadstno
 LEFT JOIN stud.ibvpos ON getpcode = ibvcode
 LEFT JOIN stud.ibdmag ON ibvcode = ibdcode
where getnumtype = 'I' and getsyscrt = 'S' 
 AND iadstno = 217244521
 AND getaddrtype = 'PA'
 AND getedate IS NULL
 AND getprimary = 'Y'
ORDER BY getsyscrt, getnumtype, getcsn
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Phlip

Comment: Move ibvpos and ibdmag conditions from the WHERE clause to ON clause to get true left join result. (WHen in WHERE, you get regular inner join result...)

Comment: Tip: When more that one table is involved, qualify all columns! (I.e. write tablename.columnname.)

Comment: Hi @jarlh, thanks for the response. I do not understand your comment om moving the ibvpos and ibdmag conditions from the WHERE clause as there is no reference to those tables in the WHERE clause. Can you clarify please? I have grown up in SQL without qualifying the columns because of the structure of the Db I am working but it is good practise.

Comment: You have to decide which *suburb name* you want to use and the join to a Derived Table/CTE instead, like `join (select ibvcode, max(ibvtown) from stud.ibvpos group by ibvcode) as ibvpos ON getpcode = ibvcode`

Comment: Thanks, @dnoeth, I have created a distinct subquery without the suburb name; I am not really interested in the name, I just need the table to join to the province table.

Comment: Why don't you add the condition you want the ON of the join you want to be so constrained? Please read & act on [mcve]. Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Justify "minimal code with a problem" for required functionality by also giving code that works for a maximal part of that functionality. Ask about the (small) difference between the examples. (These are debugging basics.)

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You likely have that. But we can't tell because you didn't give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If there is no inner join results it means, that data from getadr table does not match with data from other tables (fe there is no data or data format is different in those tables). Do you have any results from this query? Is getpcode not null and present in stud.ibvpos table?

```
  SELECT getunum, getpcode 
  FROM gen.getadr
  INNER JOIN stud.iadbio ON getunum = iadstno
  LEFT JOIN stud.ibvpos ON getpcode = ibvcode
  LEFT JOIN stud.ibdmag ON ibvcode = ibdcode
  WHERE ibvcode is not null
  AND getnumtype = 'I'
  AND getsyscrt = 'S'
  AND getaddrtype = 'PA'
  AND getedate IS NULL
  AND getprimary = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simply created a sub select that uniquely select the postal code and magisterial district like this:

```
FROM gen.getadr
  INNER JOIN stud.iadbio ON getunum = iadstno
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ibvpcode, ibvcode 
     FROM stud.ibvpos
    ) ON getpcode = ibvpcode
  INNER JOIN stud.ibdmag ON ibvcode = ibdcode
  INNER JOIN stud.innprv ON ibdprovc = innprovc
```

This gave me the results I expected.

Regards,

Phlip